# Is there a way to find array elements that use properties bound to events while using ngfor as default?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm iterating using ngFor on an array. I want to press another button that will filter that array based on a a particular property of the array object foo{bar:'New'} in that array. I want to use NgFor to initially populate and use events to further filter. Is this even possible?
object in array

```
musicArray= [{
    artist:'Foo',
    emotion:'Sad',
    linker:'./assets/music/xx.mp3',
    myImg:'./assets/images/sad.jpeg'
},
```

div that populates array:

```
<div *ngFor="let music of this.myTrack">
```

property I want to filter on:

```
<mat-card-title>{{music.emotion}}</mat-card-title>
```

this is a button I want to use to filter with:

```
 <button mat-button (click)="myEvent($event)">
```

componet code:

```
 myEvent(event) {
      event =   this.musicArray.find(x => x.emotion =="New") ; 
        this.myTrack = event;
        console.log(event);
        console.log(this.myTrack);        
        return this.myTrack;
      }

ngOnInit(){
    this.myTrack = this.musicArray;

    if(this.myEvent){
        return   this.myTrack.find(x => x.emotion =="New");
    }
}
```

currently my event comes back with the results I want but I just don't understand how to set that to the ngFor array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array.find will always return you just one element, not an array. You should do

```
this.musicArray.filter(x => x.emotion =="New")
```

This will return you a new array based on the criteria.

From what I understand of the goal you’re trying to achieve you need to run the list of music in the first place

```
<div *ngFor="let music of this.myMusic">
```

Then I would say you need to pass the wanted emotion on click. Let’s say

```
<button mat-button (click)="myEvent($event, music.emotion)">
```

Then on the component you just have to do the filtering

```
myEvent(event, emotion) {
  this.musicArray =   this.musicArray.filter(x => x.emotion === emotion) ; 
  }
```

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to make your solution a bit cleaner. You don’t need all those variables :)

Comment: Thanks again awesome.Saved me a bunch of time and headache.

Comment: Always glad to help :)